# SceneKit water like in Badger example

Tags: scenekit

Does enybody know how to create water material like in badger example from Apple?

There is a "geotherm_01" object in "scene.scn" and this object got materials "_1_terrasses_orange_water" and "_1_terrasses_eau" which creates water with slow animation that looks realistic.

I've tried to repeat same materials in my testing project but can't get the same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This water effect was achieved using [shader modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable#1654834) as shown in the SceneKit Scene Editor within Xcode. The most important material property is the [normal map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462542-normal) that will be used to affect lighting in order to simulate wavelets on a perfectly flat geometry.

[image: Badger]

More specifically the modifier for the [`.surface`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypoint/1523791-surface) entry point is

```
float waterSpeed = u_time * -0.1;vec2 uvs = _surface.normalTexcoord;uvs.x *= 2;vec3 tn = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x, uvs.y + waterSpeed)).xyz;tn = tn * 2 - 1;vec3 tn2 = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x + 0.35 , uvs.y + 0.35 + (waterSpeed * 1.3))).xyz;tn2 = tn2 * 2 - 1;vec3 rn = (tn + tn2) * 0.5;mat3 ts = mat3(_surface.tangent, _surface.bitangent, _surface.geometryNormal);_surface.normal = normalize(ts * rn);
```

Here's a commented version of the code:

```
// Elapsed time in seconds
float waterSpeed = u_time * -0.1;

// Texture coordinates that will be used to sample the normal map
vec2 uvs = _surface.normalTexcoord;
uvs.x *= 2;

// Sample the normal map
vec3 tn = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x, uvs.y + waterSpeed)).xyz;

// The texture stores values in the [0, 1] range
// Express the coordinates of the normal vector in the [-1, +1] range
tn = tn * 2 - 1;

// Sample the normal map again, using the `waterSpeed` offset this time
// in order to produce the animation effect
vec3 tn2 = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x + 0.35 , uvs.y + 0.35 + (waterSpeed * 1.3))).xyz;
tn2 = tn2 * 2 - 1;

// Combine the two normals (static and animated) to produce a richer (more complex and less uniform) effect
vec3 rn = (tn + tn2) * 0.5;

// Normals in the normal map are expressed in tangent space
// Convert them to object space and override the surface normal to simulate wavelets
mat3 ts = mat3(_surface.tangent, _surface.bitangent, _surface.geometryNormal);
_surface.normal = normalize(ts * rn);
```

Comment: Thank you mnuages.