# how water shaders are implemented in Fox application

Tags: xcode, scenekit, metal-performance-shaders

Apple have simple Fox project which demo basic SceneKit functionality. 
Can anyone explain where/how waterfall texture animation shader is implemented (also Fox2 with lava)? I know shaders can be loaded from file and bounded programmatically, but in this case shader is integrated within scene and no luck so far in getting around how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [SceneKit water like in Badger example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781235/scenekit-water-like-in-badger-example) we explain how the water effect in the Badger sample code is embedded directly in the scene file. The waterfall from Fox and lava from Fox 2 also use shader modifiers in the same way.

Comment: How do you open shaders editor within Xcode from Scene view?

Comment: In the bottom right corner of the editor you'll see an icon that looks like the one you use to show/hide the console (triangle inside a rectangle) when debugging an app.

Comment: When clicked on icon, Timeline controller pops up for selected object, or "No Selection" watermark is displayed when nothing selected...

Comment: In that pane click on "Shaders" in case "Actions" is selected.

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but I dont have Shaders option there to choose (:

Comment: This is with Xcode 9. If you are using an earlier version of Xcode, shader modifiers can be edited in the Assistant Editor.